# Android: Duration of audio song before streaming?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

**Update:**

LogCat:

```
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xabe0
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at net.website.qty.mediaplayer.Main.onListItemClick(Main.java:441)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-29 23:48:17.149: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am working on a app that stream audio song and so i am trying to show the total duration of of that audio song and here is what i have done so far but no avail. i followed this [link](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class) but still unable.

```
private TextView tv_mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds  = null;
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

...........
...........
tv_mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.duration);   
tv_mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds.setText(player.getDuration());

}
```

layout:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="136dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"          
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: what is the output your getting

Comment: i have updated my question please have a look.